# Как можно зарефакторить код уменьшив его количество?

Tags: jquery

Есть кусочек кода, который собирает с input с разными идентификаторами значения, после чего проверяет, не пусты ли они и записывает в объект. Хочу укоротить количество кода, ибо получается какая-то уж больно громоздкая констркция:

```
$('#initiate-search').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var from_iata = $('#takeoff_place').attr('iata'),
        from_name = $('#takeoff_place').val(),
        to_iata = $('#land_place').attr('iata'),
        to_name = $('#land_place').val(),
        takeoff = $('#takeoff_date').val(),
        landing = $('#back_date').val(),
        adults_num = $('#adult-counter').val(),
        teens_num = $('#teen-counter').val(),
        kids_num = $('#kid-counter').val();

    if(from_iata && from_name && to_name && to_iata && takeoff && landing && adults_num && teens_num && kids_num) { 
        $('#initiate-search').html(loader);
        $(this).off('click');
        var data = {
            from: from_iata,
            name_from: from_name,
            to: to_iata,
            name_to: to_name,
            there: moment(takeoff).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            thence: moment(landing).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            adults: parseInt(adults_num),
            teens: parseInt(teens_num),
            kids: parseInt(kids_num),
            is_business: $('#class-ident').is(':checked') ? true : false,
            is_oneway: $('#class-ident').is(':checked') ? true : false
        }
        //do smth
    }
});
```

Comment: Подход неправильный (ИМХО).  Названия ключей `data` должны совпадать с названиями полей формы. Тогда получение значений формы можно было бы устроить через `$('form').serializeArray()` или через встроенный `FormData`. Обычно сама форма(HTML) - в точности должна совпадать c отправляемыми данными (в том числе ajax-ом) - иначе появляется куча ненужных прослоек.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр так просто не получится, потому что перед отправкой сложные вычисления происходят, например, _moment(takeoff).format('YYYY-MM-DD')_. Кроме того, не все значения берутся из полей ввода, некоторые берутся из атрибутов

Comment: _получается какая-то уж больно громоздкая конструкция_ - какая именно конструкция кажется громоздкой?

Comment: @Grundy , не так просто - но было бы 4 дополнительные строчки, вместо 20 :) И в конце концов есть hidden-поля, в которые обычно можно вести запись (вместо записи в аттрибуты) - тогда будет больше HTML но меньше JS, что обычно позитивно.

Comment: @Grundy условие длиннющее, например.